# How do I find an error bound for a Taylor Series if the f(x) is not provided, but I am given the associated Taylor Series?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Given the Taylor series
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i\frac{(3n+1)}{2^n}(x-2)^i ,$$
>   if the $3$rd degree Taylor polynomial for $f$ centered at $x=2$ is used to approximate $f\left(\frac94\right)$, what is the alternating series error bound?"

Now I understand how to get the approximation 
$$T_3\left(\frac94\right)= 1-2\left(\frac94-2\right)+\frac74\left(\frac94-2\right)^2-\frac54\left(\frac94-2\right)^3 .$$

What I don't understand is how do I calculate the error bound without knowing the original function. I know the formula for the bound on $R_n(x)$, but it requires knowing $f(x)$, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! I've taken the liberty of reformatting for readability and adjusting some wording for clarity. Please ensure that the changes preserve the intended meaning and edit as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

"... what is the ***alternating series*** error bound?"

This is not asking for the Taylor series error.  It is asking for the alternating series error.  For a convergent alternating series, the sum of the series is bounded by any two successive partial sums.  Thus, the $3^\text{rd}$ degree Taylor approximation at $9/4$ and the $4^\text{th}$ degree Taylor apprixmation at $9/4$ form an interval containing the value of the function at $9/4$.  The error is bounded by the width of the interval.

Comment: Did you choose the 3rd degree and the 4th degree for the error bound b/c its 3rd degree approximation?

So are you essentially saying T4-T3=Error Bound?

Comment: Well, $|T_4 - T_3|$ is the error bound, because I'm too lazy to figure out which one is bigger than the other.  You could take the $2^\text{nd}$ and $3^\text{rd}$ degree as a successive pair, which would also bound the error.  But really, that's telling you about the error in $T_2$.